# How to disable click button?

Tags: java, android

i have two button and i want disable click button runtime if file doesn't exist in folder .. but problem the button install is disable all time .. why ?

```
        Button install = (Button) findViewById(R.id.install);
        final File file_1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
        if(file_1.exists()){
            install.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"+"app-debug.apk")),
                            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });

        }else {

            install.setEnabled(false);

        }

    }
```

if add install.setEnabled(false); in onResume() the button disable all time but if delete from onResume() .. work good  :(

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
        final Button down = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);
        down.setEnabled(!file.exists());
        final Button install = (Button) findViewById(R.id.install);
        install.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have:

onCreate method :

```
    Button install = (Button) findViewById(R.id.install);
    install.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"+"app-debug.apk")),
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
```

onResume method:

```
     @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app-debug.apk");
            final Button down = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);
            down.setEnabled(!file.exists());
            final Button install = (Button) findViewById(R.id.install);
            install.setEnabled(file.exists());
        }
```

Comment: Haha .. I'm trying to solve it about two hours and the solution is simple as I explained .. thanks :)